# Date objects with wtforms_sqlalchemy.orm.model_form

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I don't succeed in setting a date value in my model using model_form:

```python
@app.route('/admin/article/<int:id>', methods=['PUT'])
@login_required
def admin_update(id):
    ArticleForm = model_form(Article, Form)

    article = Article.query.get_or_404(id)
    form    = ArticleForm(request.form, article)

    if form.validate():
        form.populate_obj(article)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(status='success', article=article.as_dict()), 200

    # Invalid
    return jsonify(status='error', errors=form.errors), 400
```

My model looks as this:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id    = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True)
    lead  = db.Column(db.Text)
    body  = db.Column(db.Text)
    date  = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, id=None, title=None, lead=None, body=None, date=None):
        self.id    = id
        self.title = title
        self.lead  = lead
        self.body  = body
        self.date  = date

    def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

I export the article as dict, so I convert it into JSON. My JS based WYSIWYG editor dumps all data (title/lead/body/date) in an XHR request and sends it to above API point.

The response I get from this call:

```js
{
  "errors": {
    "date": [
      "Not a valid datetime value"
    ]
  }, 
  "status": "error"
}
```

I know I try to set a string (current format dd-mm-yyyy `28-03-2017`) for an Sqlalchemy `DateTime`, but how can I convert this? I can adjust the format to anything required, but I would like to stick to my simple view with `model_form`.

Tools used:

1. flask
2. flask_wtf.Form
3. wtforms_sqlalchemy.orm.model_form (no wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not with Model or SqlAlchemy, but with form.

As I can see your date column is DateTime(not Date). Here is a small example of Form which can explain the problem:

```
# flask forms uses the same fields
from wtforms import Form, DateTimeField

class ArticleForm(Form):
    date = DateTimeField('Date')

form_data = MultiDict()
# your format of date dd-mm-yyyy - 28-03-2017
date = '28-03-2017'
form_data.add('date', date)
article = ArticleForm(form_data)
print article.validate() # False
```

Why this happened? Because DateTimeField has different [default format](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L728) - `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

How to fix it? The easiest way is just to set your format to `date field` of form:

```
class ArticleForm(Form):
    date = DateTimeField('Date', format='%d-%m-%Y')

form_data = MultiDict()
form_data.add('date', '28-03-2017')
article = ArticleForm(form_data)
print article.validate() # True
```

Another way is to convert date manually:

```
form_data = MultiDict()
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('28-03-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
form_data.add('date', '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(date))
article = ArticleForm(form_data)
print article.validate() # True
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used the default format in the request, everything worked perfectly. Just stupid I didn't question the format itself :D